# IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 ASP Classic/Active-X COM DLL issues writing to UNC shared folder

Tags: iis, permissions, streamwriter

I have spent 12 hours on this, tried everything that I have read about, but I cannot get a new server farm we have,the website to write to a shared folder.

I have set the application pools, even temporarily (just to try it out) to admin accounts and even set the folder to be available for "everyone".

We have a network specialist who cannot figure it out either, in his favour he does not understand IIS very well and keeps away from it, but at the end of the day, its just a User account and permissions as far as I can see and I have set up the exact same website on a previous W2012 server and IIS 8.5, 7.5 and 6 without major issues (abeit registering 32bit DLLs in a 64bit environment) but all that has gone well and no issue (except for reading and writing to a shared folder).

SO breaking it down to its simplest form, I used a simple FSO script to write a text file in the shared folder, this clearly came back with "Permission denied line X".

Running the script through cscript as a VBS file, it works, running it through IIS. No chance.

Im not going to give up, but running as the top admin login (I had the network guy use HIS identity in the application pool) its not happening.

32bit has been enabled, yes, folder permissions set, yes.

Im at my wits end with the thing. Anything to suggest, I would be happy to listen and try.

Thanks all.

Update: I can write to the same MACHINE as IIS, any folder as long as I set the appropriate permissions. The difference between from this shared folder (I am working on a server farm, I forgot to mention that) is - when you do the security, locations "IIS AppPool\poolidentity" to add the user, it works on the same server, when I try to add that user on the shared folder on the networked server, that user does not appear - does this give any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - for me, after all the right things that I had done, was something I had not tried.

Select the site in IIS, so you sell all the icons for ASP, Authentication, Autohorization Rules, CGI etc.. - select the Authentication and Open Feature
You will see Anonymous Authentication (Enabled), ASP.NET Impersonation (Disabled), Basic Authentication (Disabled) and so on.
Select the Anonymous Authentication, right click Edit - by default it was set to "Specific User" IUSR - now for me, that did not work - so clicked on Application Pool Identity and boom, now its working.

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: I request you to mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issues.

Comment: how do I do that? I added answer but not sure how to mark it as answered, sorry

Comment: To accept an answer, click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons:[img](https://i.imgur.com/VugknfH.png)